# Long waiting List for Internet: What are these IP addresses?

Tags: networking, ip, bandwidth

I am having a problem of *slow Internet Browsing speed*.

When I checked it with *NetHogs* there was a huge list waiting for Internet.

[image]

What are these IP addresses ? How can I find them ?

Is it due to a *normal* Ubuntu process or *abnormal* process ?

Comment: There are only 2 programs that uses internet in my system (my browser+unknown TCP), you can find the PROGRAM NAME by maximizing the terminal if it is too long...

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at: http://whois.net/reverse-dns-ip-lookup/

Most things are just update checks, etc. It is most likely a normal process.

But do check that link.

Ciao!